# Python Binary SearchTree

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

```
class SearchTree:
   def __init__(self, items = None):         
       if items:
         self.tree = [None, None, None]
         for item in items:
             self.add(item)
     else:
         return None
  def add(self, item):
     if self.tree[2] == None:
         self.tree[2] = item
     if self.tree[2] > item:
         self.tree[0] = self .add(item)
     if self.tree[2] < item:
         self.tree[1] = self.add(item)
     elif self.tree[2] == item:
         pass
     return self.tree
if __name__ == "__main__":
 a = [1,2,3]
 b = SearchTree(a)
```

Why do i keep guetting a RecursionError? I am still a Rookie when it comes to classes but i can't figure it out...

Comment: Well you call `self.add` in the `add` function while it is possible nothing changes on the state of your object. So in that case it will start looping.

Comment: Thanks, i see the problem! Any idea on how to change the code (if possible) without the need of a new parameter?